# Can someone explain how Castle Windsor is working in my app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have begun using Castle Windsor and somehow my app is all up and running but I dont really understand how its working.  Don't refer me to the documentation as I wouldn't be here otherwise.

In my Global.asax.cs I have this:

```
private static IWindsorContainer container;

protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BootstrapContainer();
} 

protected void Application_End()
{
  container.Dispose();
}

private static void BootstrapContainer()
{
 container = new WindsorContainer()
                .Install(FromAssembly.This());

 var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
 ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
}
```

Now this is registering a new controller factory which I understand.  The installation of a WindsorContainer from the current assembly I think registers all installers for example I have a repository installer.  I assume that the container that is created in Global.asax is passed to the installers.

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
     public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {

        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
                 .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                 .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                 .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
    }
}
```

In my controller I have created a constructor and passed in a IRepository argument.  What I dont understand is how the controller accepts this argument.

Secondly as a test I created 2 repository classes that implement a IRepository.  Putting a breakpoint in the controller constructor it passes in one of these classes.  How do I map what class that implements IRepository should be passed to the constructor?

I also have Fluent NHibernate up and running. For the next stage I would like the IRepository to have a dependency on the ISession.  How do I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have registered a controller factory that uses Windsor, it is the Windsor IoC container that is responsible for *resolving* all your controller instances as and when they are needed.

That is, when you access a URL in your MVC project that points to the action "Index" on your "HomeController" your WindsorControllerFactory will be asked, by the MVC framework, for an instance of HomeController.

If that controller has a constructor which takes an instance of IRepository *and you have registered IRepository as a service with the container* then Windsor will know how to satisfy the dependency of the HomeController class. Therefore it can first resolve IRepository into some concrete class, instantiate this, and pass it in as a parameter to the HomeController constructor before returning the instance of HomeController to the MVC framework.

If you need different implementations of IRepository for different purposes (i.e. a UserRepository and a ProductRepository) you could create separate interfaces for these, each of which extend IRepository, e.g.:

```
public interface IProfileRepository : IRepository {}
```

Then you can use Windsor's fluent registration API to register all concrete classes that implement IRepository, and have them registered by the specific service they provide, e.g. IProfileRepository.

If you do this, Windsor will automatically resolve all instances that implement IRepository for you without you having to write any new registration code when you add a new implementation.

As for making your repository classes depend on ISession, you can do this in a number of ways. I would recommend *not* letting them depend directly on a session, but rather let them depend on a class through which they can obtain the current session (so that you can share sessions between repositories). There's lots of information on why this is good practice out there on the web, just do a search.

Now, as for actually making it happen, you can either:

- Register an instance of a class (by interface) that will retrieve a session for you with Windsor and let Windsor resolve this class as a parameter to your repository constructors.
- Register ISession with Windsor and use a factory method to retrieve it when it is resolved.

Comment: Excellent response thanks however there are 2 questions I have.  In my repository installer it regsiters all repositories. I have created 2 classes that implement the same IRepository just out of curisoity.  In the constructor Windsor has obviously decided to send in one of those classes. What determines that, why didnt it choose the other class? I assume I am better off mapping the repositories to the class rather than the generic approach I'm doing now.

Comment: I have also followed this tutorial about exposing ISession  http://bit.ly/gEokB1  I have then in my classes that implement IRepository created a constructor that have a ISession argument. Do you think thats acceptable? Thanks

Comment: To answer your last question first: Yes, this is fine. Off the top of my head I think that will give you a new instance of ISession every time you resolve a repository (I may be wrong!) which is not necessarily ideal - you may want to share an instance of ISession across several repositories for performance benefits. I'll see if I can find links to info on this, but a general idea would be to create and store an ISession in HttpContext.Items[] - and reuse that instance for every IRepository (this is, effectively, a single ISession per web request).

Comment: And to answer your first question: Windsor will always return the first registered component for a service. If you register IRepository with two different concrete classes it will always pick the first one. That's why I suggest using different interfaces for each repository, where they all implement IRepository. That way you can have one registration statement which picks all classes that implement IRepository, and registers them with their own service (e.g. UserRepository).

Comment: To register all instances of IRepository you can use code like this:

container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(_assemblyName).Pick()
                                   .If(t => t.FindInterfaces((t1, o) => t1.Name == "IRepository", null).Length > 0)
                                   .BasedOn(typeof (IRepository<>))
                                   .WithService
                                   .FromInterface(typeof (IRepository<>))
                                   .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient));

Comment: The next step in the above link (http://bit.ly/ewIBpX) seems to suggest it is just one ISession per request but I may not be reading it correctly

Comment: Strangely on part 6 it says its more than one instance of ISession but in part 7 it seems to suggest one ISession per request. This stuff is very complicated :-)

Comment: Just for my reference really but as far as I understand it, controllers are transient as they need to be created for each web request and are then released in the controller factory. A repository and ISession need to be PerWebRequest and the release is handled automatically by Windsor

Comment: I've created 2 repositories with a dependency on ISession and 2 controllers which have a constructor argument of a repository.  On each controller constructor I can look into the passed repository and view some statistics about the session and on both controllers the ISession sessionfactory statistics start time is the same so I'm naievely concluding that the session is shared which is strange because if its lifecycle is perwebrequest then I would have thought it would get created each request

Comment: Hi Jon. If you've configured windsor according to that article you will get one session per web request. The Session *factory* on the other hand, should be a singleton for your application - which is why you'd see the same stats on your ISession instances. Does that make sense?